# How to use Sigma.js in React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, import, sigma.js

I'm trying to set up a simple web app with React/TypeScript so I can fiddle with some graphs with Sigma.js. But I can't get the end result to render anything with Sigma.

Here's the steps I followed:

```
$ npx create-react-app sigmafiddle --template typescript^C
$ cd sigmafiddle
$ yarn add sigma
$ yarn add @types/sigmajs
```

However, when I go to import Sigma I encounter the following problems:

```
import { sigma } from 'sigma'
```

Fails with this error message:

> TypeScript error in ~/devel/sigmafiddle/src/App.tsx(4,23):
>   Could not find a declaration file for module 'sigma'. '~/devel/sigmafiddle/node_modules/sigma/endpoint.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/sigma` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'sigma';`  TS7016
>   Not a real helpful message, since @types/sigma does not exist within npm.

And if I try this:

```
import { sigma } from 'sigmajs'
```

I get this failure:

> TypeScript error in ~/devel/sigmafiddle/src/App.tsx(4,23):
>   File '~/devel/sigmafiddle/node_modules/@types/sigmajs/index.d.ts' is not a module.  TS2306

I've also tried the package `react-sigma`:

```
yarn add react-sigma

// in app.tsx
import {Sigma, RandomizeNodePositions, RelativeSize} from 'react-sigma';
```

Unfortunately there is no `@types/react-sigma` package, so this results in the following error:

> Cannot find module 'react-sigma'

How can I get sigma.js to work with TypeScript and React?

Answer (score 1):

#### You didn't import what you are trying to use

replace

```
/// <reference types="@types/sigmajs" />
```

to

```
import { sigma } from 'sigma';
```

Usually, import as above is the common way to use lib in js/ts project.

---

#### Update

Since the error seems to be lacking type definition of the lib,

> File '~/devel/graph-grammar/node_modules/@types/sigmajs/index.d.ts' is not a module.

```sh
npm install --save @types/sigmajs
```

And import as normal may work.

```
import { sigma } from 'sigma';
```

Refer to [@types/sigmajs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/sigmajs)

---

#### Update No.2

You may need **react-sigma** [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-sigma), [repo](https://github.com/dunnock/react-sigma) in your react project instead.

Install it, and import refer to the document seems fine.

```
import {Sigma, RandomizeNodePositions, RelativeSize} from 'react-sigma';
```

If that not work, try to install both `sigma` and `react-sigma`, since `ploty.js` need both `ploty.js` and `react-ploty.js` been installed, I guess you may meet the similar situation.

---

#### Update No.3

Seems **react-sigma** don't support `typescript`, they support `flow-type` instead.

[image: Edit elegant-banzai-22gbb]

Refer: document of [react-sigma](https://github.com/dunnock/react-sigma/blob/master/DOCS.md#sigma)

Comment: As I said in the OP, import statements don't work. The compiler errors with `File '~/devel/graph-grammar/node_modules/@types/sigmajs/index.d.ts' is not a module.`

I'll try out react-sigma. I don't see typescript bindings for it so I may just have to drop down to regular old javascript.

Comment: OK I've rewritten the question. Also, importing @types/sigmajs still doesn't work with the import statement.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last solution. I can install sigma and react-sigma together but I don't get the type bindings for TypeScript from either of those packages. I've verified that react-sigma works standalone in a pure JS application, the problem is that I'm encountering really seems specific to TypeScript and not having the correct type bindings. Maybe they just don't exist for sigmajs.